# Xamarin Forms - How to create a global list<object> that I can use across different pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use a List across different pages. I have two different listviews that need to use the same List. The first list view is used in my searchbar view and the second is were I use the get a listview of all the items in a specific category.

Ex: if i had a list that i use in the search bar where i can search all the students based on their name and then i want to create listview in a different page that has a listview that shows all the students based of their age.

Edit: I have already tried creating a singleton class and the page will not recognize that data in the class exists so i cannot use or edit it.

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `List<>` in the `App` class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static List<string> myList { get; set; } 

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myList = new List<string>();

        MainPage = new MainPage();

    }
}
```

And then you can access this list in different by:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<string> tempList = App.myList;
}
```